# I can't get my background to fill the entire screen using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile

All I can get is a banner type of picture under the header. It isn't fitting the screen for width and height, which is what I want so different phone sizes will adjust. I've researched a lot but I can't get it. Here is the image of what I'm getting. I want the picture to fill the entire page, between the header and footer, and I want it to adjust for screen size.

Now getting this issue. Also the background is going on all of m pages and I just want it at home.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

 #background {
background: url(landscape.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:center center;
background-size:100% 100%;
}


.ui-page {
background: transparent;
}
.ui-content{
background: transparent;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="Home" >

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <a href="#bars" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-    iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Bars</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" id="background">
    <p>Home.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use **.ui-content** class in order to add/edit style for the content.

Try using this CSS:

```
.ui-content {
background: transparent url(http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Ideal-landscape.jpg);
background-size :cover; // or you can leave as 100% 100%
color:#FFFFFF;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

.ui-page {
background: transparent;
}
```

And the following JS/Jquery:

```
$(document).delegate('#Home', 'pageshow', function () {
var the_height = ($(window).height() - $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').height() - $(this).find('[data-role="footer"]').height());
$(this).height($(window).height()).find('[data-role="content"]').height(the_height);
});
```

**UPDATE**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oq8z09z2/1/)

Comment: If I do this, how do I connect the Jquery and CSS to my main html file? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Put the CSS code between the inside the <head></head> tags, in a style tag: <style> Copy/Paste here the css code </style>   . Also in the <head></head> put the JS/jQuery code between <script></script> tags. Take a look at this two examples for css and for js in the head:

Comment: What about the Javascript file?

Comment: Those are for testing purposes, if you want to make a big application, you will need to create external CSS and external JS files (loaded in the <head></head> also, but the code is not copy pasted there....the code will be in separate files). For example on the following link, you will see the external css and scripts loaded in the header: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages/

Comment: Thank you, those were very helpful and the code worked! However, it is now giving me a scroll bar even with background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: Try to add overflow:hidden; at the .ui-content class. Or : body{overflow:hidden;}    And please mark my answer as accepted if it helped :D  . Don't hesitate to ask more stuff here.

Comment: Take a look also over here in order to learn and find more possible responsive background image methods : http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fullscreen-background-image-plugins/

Comment: My picture is wide, so maybe that is why even with the overflow, at some sizes of the window the scroll bar will appear? What size should I make the image in terms of LxW Pixels? Will the photo adjust to different sized screens or do I have to crate logic for screen sizes to select a corresponding image?

Comment: As Benoît Da Silva texted here, background-size:cover; does the magic in most casese. Provide us a JSfiddle so we can help you more. (1. Go on jsfiddle.net and create account 2. In the left-top part select your jquery framework + jquery mobile framework 3. Copy paste your html, css , js code in their specific CODE box.  --> in order to see your image, please upload it on a picture sharing website, and use that link for it.  4. Save the jsfiddle and give us the link.)

Comment: I can do that but I'm not sure how if I am using Jquery Mobile.

Comment: I cant get the image to work. Here is the link though: https://jsfiddle.net/chadwell1028/56k0qhju/12/

Comment: Also, I only want the background on the home page. For some reason my home page has a scroll bar and white space at the bottom, not sure why.

Comment: Justin, you were adding a not working image address, this one: http://tinypic.com/r/23sir1g/8   .... And also you are using some HTML tags in the CSS part in JsFiddle. Please check my update at the answer...you have a working example of jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/oq8z09z2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-size:cover;
```

Or maybe you could provide a link to your problem ?